# Javascript thousand separator on negative and decimal number without leading zeroes

Tags: javascript

I am making a table that has input with price on every row, so when the user input positive number, or negative number, or decimal number or negative with decimal number, it need to has thousand separator on the number and should not have leading zeroes. I am avoiding library because using library, I need to change so much code, but i am welcome on library with minor fix. There are many stackoverflow's post on thousand separator without leading zeroes, but the post only dealing with one type number like positive or negative number, what I need is a number that is negative and  decimal as well. I prefer regular expression so I don't have to change a lot of code.

Comment: Will you share your problem? Add more details.

Comment: i am making a table that has input with price on every row, so when the user input positive number, or negative number, or decimal number or negative with decimal number, it need to has thousand separator on the number.

Comment: If what you want is a regular expression exactly, please also post examples of the numbers you want to match and make reference to post you read, even if they did not solve your problem. That will guide those who would like to help you.